# Linq to compare two collections in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare two collections in C# that I'm currently doing using nested "for" loop. is there a way in Linq to do the same which will be quicker and more efficient? here is my current code which works perfectly just looking for an efficient way:

```
OrgCollection myYears = Org.RetrieveDistinctYear();
if (myYears.Count > 0)
{
AcademicYearCollection allYears = AcademicYear.RetrieveAll();
for (int i = 0; i < myYears.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < allYears.Count; j++)
    {
        if (myYears[i].AcademicYearCode == allYears[j].Code)
        {
        ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(allYears[j].Name,allYears[j].Code));
        break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to compare "Code" from AcademicYearCollection with the "AcademicYearCode" property in OrgCollection & if it is the same then add it in the Dropdownlist "ddlYear".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sort them and compare in one loop.

Comment: try that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102661/compare-two-list-elements-with-linq?rq=1)

conclusion for future. Make some research before you post any question

Comment: how many items do you anticipate from `RetrieveDistinctYear`

Comment: something that will increase over time and has a lot of data already in it.

Comment: Then the Dictionary approach in my answer may well be faster, you will have to test to see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it in LINQ, which gives shorter code. To know if it is more efficient or not you would have to profile it. I think that linq's join operator uses some kind of hash buckets inernally which should give better performance, especially if the collections are large. Your current solution is O(N^2) which will quickly degrade if the number of options increases.

```
OrgCollection myYears = Org.RetrieveDistinctYear();
AcademicYearCollection allYears = AcademicYear.RetrieveAll();

var items = from y in myYears
            join ay in allYears
            on y.Code equals ay.AcademicYearCode
            select new { ay.Name, ay.Code }
```

Comment: Anders in response to the deleted comment, you can actually use `Intersect` if you pass your own IEqualityComparer. But this is much nicer :)

Comment: except, you don't need the intersect, just the first match

Comment: This expression will compute all matches but the question only asks for the first. Subsequent processing is wasted effort.

Comment: @Jodrell: you're right, I didn't see the `break` in the original question, so this will indeed return a separate result, if there are multiple matches. If there only is one match however it will be the same, but non-O(N^2) (if I've understood linq's join correctly).

Comment: or no matches :-), Jon Skeet states here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271615/better-performance-on-updating-objects-with-linq that `Join` generates a `Lookup` internally, therefore I concur that `Join` will benefit from hashing.

Answer (score 0):

```
OrgCollection myYears = Org.RetrieveDistinctYear();
if (myYears.Count > 0)
{
    AcademicYearCollection allYears = AcademicYear.RetrieveAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < myYears.Count; i++)
    {
         if (allYears[j].Any(allY => allY ==  myYears[i].AcademicYearCode ))
            {
                ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(allYears[j].Name, allYears[j].Code));
                break;
            }

    }
}
```

This could be an option but i think the extension method 'any' works the same way by doing an iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has similar speed and efficiency to your original solution, but it can be parallelized by changing `from y in myYears` to `from y in myYears.AsParallel()` to possibly speed it up.

```
OrgCollection myYears = Org.RetrieveDistinctYear();
AcademicYearCollection allYears = AcademicYear.RetrieveAll();

var items = from y in myYears
            let match = allYears.FirstOrDefault( ay => y.AcademicYearCode == ay.Code)
            where match != null
            select new ListItem(match.Name, match.Code);
```