# Compare and check collections using LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, collections

I have to compare 2 collections and check if the `transactionId` in the `TransactionLevelCommentsCollection` exists in the `TransactionCommentsCollection`. If exists throw an alert of the `TransactionLinq.Key`.

//Code

```
      For Each Record In (From TransactionCommentLinq In Me.TransactionCommentsCollection
                                    Join TransactionLinq In Me.TransactionsCollection On TransactionLinq.TransactionId Equals TransactionCommentLinq.TransactionId
                                    Join TaskLinq In Me.WorkflowsController.TasksController.TasksCollection On TaskLinq.TaskId Equals TransactionCommentLinq.TaskId
                                    Select TransactionLinq.Key,TransactionLinq.TransactionId, TaskLinq.TaskId Distinct)

// Have to check the values exists in TransactionLevelCommentsCollection here 
    Next
```

The record returns the transactionId and with that i have to check inside the `TransactionLevelCommentsCollection`

Comment: It looks like VB but you tagged your question as C#...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim rec = From TransactionCommentLinq In Me.TransactionCommentsCollection
          Join TransactionLinq In Me.TransactionsCollection On TransactionLinq.TransactionId Equals TransactionCommentLinq.TransactionId
          Join TaskLinq In Me.WorkflowsController.TasksController.TasksCollection On TaskLinq.TaskId Equals TransactionCommentLinq.TaskId
          Select TransactionLinq.Key,TransactionLinq.TransactionId, TaskLinq.TaskId Distinct
```

Since you want to compare values of `TransactionId` only:

```
Dim transIds = rec.Select(Function(r) r.TransactionId)
```

Now you get a list of TransactionId's from the long linq above. Let's assume the value type is same as in your `TransactionLevelCommentsCollection`'s `TransactionId`

Use `Intersect`:

```
Dim idExist = transIds.Intersect(TransactionLevelCommentsCollection.Select(Function(x) x.TransactionId)
```

Now `idExist` will contains list of ids exist in both collections.

**UPDATE BASED ON NEW REQUIREMENT**

Since OP needs the `Key` instead of the `TransactionID`, there are 3 ways to get the `Key`s.

**Method 1:**
Continued from the method shown above, get the `Key` value of items using:

```
For Each id In idExist 
    rec.First(Function(o) o.TransactionId = id).Key
Next
```

**Method 2:**
The codes below is a totally rewritten (not related to the method shown above) and it will return `rec` objects from the LINQ above that has `TransactionID` that exist in `TransactionLevelCommentsCollection`:

```
Dim xrec = rec.Where(Function(o) TransactionLevelCommentsCollection.Exists(Function(tlc) tlc.TransactionId = o.TransactionId))
```

Well, actually this code will loop each `TransactionLevelCommentsCollection` items checking for `TransactionId` that match `TransactionId` in each `rec` items. The difference is it is done in 1 line of code.

**Method 3:**
This one also a totally rewritten code, using join query:

```
Dim xrec = From r In rec
           From tlc In TransactionLevelCommentsCollection
           Where r.TransactionId = tlc.TransactionId
           Select r.TransactionId, r.Key
```

Now xrec contain list of items from `rec` with each corresponding `TransactionID` and `Key` properties where its `TransactionID` exists in `TransactionLevelCommentsCollection`.

Comment: Add a close braces')' at the end of 'intersect' function.

Comment: Can i get the Key along with the transactionId?

Answer (score 0):

just do like this

```
var GetCollection=(From TransactionCommentLinq In Me.TransactionCommentsCollection
                                Join TransactionLinq In Me.TransactionsCollection On TransactionLinq.TransactionId Equals TransactionCommentLinq.TransactionId
                                Join TaskLinq In Me.WorkflowsController.TasksController.TasksCollection On TaskLinq.TaskId Equals TransactionCommentLinq.TaskId
                                Select TransactionLinq.Key,TransactionLinq.TransactionId, TaskLinq.TaskId Distinct).Tolist();

Get another collection of TransactionCommentsCollection like var SearchList=Db.tblTransactionCommentsCollection.tolist()
Foreach(var Obj in GetCollection)
{
      for(int i=0;i<  SearchList.count();i++)
       {
              if(Obj.transactionId==SearchList.elementat(i).transactionId)
                  {
                        messageBox()/Alert(SearchList.elementat(i).transactionId);
                        break;
                   }
       }
}
```

I do not know It would serve you as you want but in this I have got two list. One is your result set and other in which you have to search the particular Item. This syntax is of c#. you can do this is VB and please Mark the answer useful if it works for you.

Comment: There can be a much simpler way i hope so.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344591/linq-to-compare-two-collections-in-c-sharp